# Suggested edits on answers show the author of the parent question instead of the answer's author as they used to

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, user-interface, information-display

In [this suggested edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152203) on [an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/276632/120114) it shows [the user that asked the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/258744/dokichan) above the revision and the user that proposed the edit below it. [The answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/276632/120114) was posted by a different user and that is not visible on the suggested edit queue item.

[image]

Shouldn't it show the user that answered the question instead of the user that asked the question?

Comment: This is annoying when the suggested edit is adding a comment into the answer because you don't know if it's the answerer's comment or not.